# Pentaho Formula

Tags: formula, pentaho, pdi

I am new to Pentaho, so please be gentle.

I am, perhaps naively, wanting to use a Formula to convert a six-character string in the form YYYYMM to the date representing the final day of that month.

I imagine doing this step by step using successive lines of the Formula: checking that the string is of the correct length and, if so:

- extracting the year and converting it to integer (with error checking)
- extracting the month and converting it to integer (also with error checking)
- converting ([year], [month], 1) to a date (the first of the month)
- adding a month
- subtracting a day

Some of those steps may be combined but, overall, it relies on a succession of steps to achieve a final result.

Formula does not seem to recognise the values achieved along the way though, at least not by enclosing them in square brackets as you do with fields from previous objects in the mapping.

I suppose I could have a series of Formula objects one after the other in the mapping but that seems untidy and inefficient. If a single Formula object cannot have a series of values defined on successive lines, what is the point of even having lines? How do I use a value I have defined on a previous line?

Answer (score 0):

The formula step isn’t the best way to achieve that. The resulting formula will be hard to read and quite cumbersome.

It’s better (and faster) to use a calculator step. A javascript step can also be used, and it will be easier to read, but slower (though that probably won't be a major issue).

So, one way forward is to implement this on a calculator step:

1. Create a copy of your string field as a Date
2. Create 2 constant fields: 1 and -1
3. Add 1 month to the date field
4. Subtract 1 day to the result
5. Create a copy of the result as a string.

See screenshot:
[image: Calculator step]

Comment: Hey, that worked.  Thank you.

Should I be surprised that you actually have to specify 1 and -1 as constants and can't just enter them as Field B?  It looks like the Conversion Mask can just be entered freely, using the dropdown values only as suggestions.  However, the Fields need to be previously defined names, not simply values.

I have a lot to learn but, with 20+ years' experience using other ETL tools, such as Informatica, I am finding the transition mostly intuitive.